# How do I transfer items from K2 to Joomla articles or wordpress ? What is the most wise choice?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I feel fed up with the Joomla K2 extension. This is the most crappy extension I've ever used and I am tired of correcting mistakes and bugs all the time. Even in the K2 forums, most of the threads suddenly and strangely disappeared, leading google results to 404 pages.

I did the most foolish thing on joomla: I installed their extension in joomla 1.6 because I wanted to set featured images in every article and joomla didn't have something like that (and then upgraded to 2.5) . So I created a news portal that publishes about 6 articles (or K2 items) every day for a year. So far there are 10 categories, 1000 articles and 200 tags (and 4 users only). There is nothing complicated on the website and all components are used "as they are". I haven't even used K2 extra fields etc.

I desperately want to transfer all items, categories, tags and images from K2 to Joomla articles. Then I will upgrade to the new Joomla 3.0. If I had a choice, I would transfer all data to wordpress. I have no money to hire an experienced developer and I have advanced programming knowledge but I am not an expert. I can try to copy data from one column to another but I would really appreciate the opinion of a developer with a "strong" knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

On [Joomla's forums](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2528965) it says that:

> K2 articles are stored in the table jos_k2_items. Use a sql query to
>   copy them to jos_content.

```
INSERT INTO ###_content (title, alias, catid, published, introtext, fulltext)
SELECT title, alias, catid, published, introtext, fulltext
FROM ###_k2_items ;
```

This was posted about Joomla 1.5 Check the new table structure and make the necessary changes.

Comment: I have seen this thread. Things have changed from 1.5 to 2.5 and the biggest problem is images... K2 Item featured image must be transferred to joomla articles.

Comment: Brian Teeman blogged about a similar mgration. You move the images to the new images (intro image and fulltext image) fields in content.

However you must be extremely careful because in Joomla 2.5/3 you have to deal with the asset table and make sure that is set up correctly.

Comment: Elin can you please post the link from Brian Teeman's blog that says about K2 and joomla? I searched around in his website and I wasn't able to find anything similar.

Comment: please help me escape the K2 hell. This is the worst choice I have ever made in a CMS system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure are you still looking for the answer, but maybe others do.

In case you want to move your K2 to WordPress, there's a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-joomla-k2-to-wp-website-migration/) at the WordPress plugin directory for an automated migration. It supports the import of different type of content including categories, tags, menus and other, so it might answer your request.

The quick guide to the process includes the following steps -

1. You install the plugin on your WP website
2. Create the account at the service
3. Download the extension and install it at your K2 website
4. Choose the entities you want to migrate
5. Try the trial migration (it migrates 10 posts)
6. If you like it you can try the full migration (it's not free)

You may refer to [this](https://cms2cms.com/blog/joomla-k2-wordpress-migration-plugin-works/) for more info, plus, this service is also represented in [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Joomla).

Hope it helps.